# How to show a stack trace reports of unhandled exceptions in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling, stack-trace

I using this EventHandler to catch all unhandled exceptions.

```
 public App()
        : base()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
    }

  void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I want to show the stack trace of the exeption (except the error message) like in this picture:
[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might not have understood this question because to my understanding, it seems to be quite a simple question. There is a `StackTrace` property on the `Exception` class. You can get the stack trace from that property:

```
private void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, 
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    string stackTrace = e.Exception.StackTrace;
}
```

You can find out more from the [`Exception` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN. Please let me know if I have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I forgot to change that... that's the problem with copy and pasting. Thanks for pointing that out.